# echo strange characters appearing on string from server

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, echo

I consistently have the following prefix output when using a simple echo statement from the server

> ```   The string I am echoing - notice these 3 apostrohe look like characters at the beginning, always shows in threes.

Here is my header information, which I made sure had the charset to UTF-8,

```
header information: {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 40;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Sat, 12 Oct 2013 05:10:31 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.25 (Amazon)";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.27";
}
```

I made sure my httpd.config file had the `AddDefaultCharset` attribute set to UTF-8
I tried to have the .htaccess file contain the following: `IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8`
I also tried to ensure the default encoding option in the php.ini file was set to `utf8`
But nothing is working. This change is all of a sudden, this did not used to happen before

I just don't understand what is happening, since my application is now on standby since strings arent being received correctly, everything was fine for the last 8-9 months. Note, I did have my amazon ec2 instance elastic ip address mapped onto a custom domain name. I doubt this has anything to do with this situation. But please do tell me if you know why these characters are being outputted?
Thank you

Comment: I'm no encoding expert, could it be a [BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) ?

Comment: I thought it might have been something like that, I wasn't aware of the term though, however, I did not have this problem before; for it to appear 8 months after developing just blows my mind away. I could use a quick dirty metod to ignore the BOM at the beginning of each of my responses,however for me to have to deal with strings like this is not acceptable as my current application is already online and don't want to push unnecessary updates just to add a BOM fix, when it should be fixable elsewhere. Frustrating when you haven't done anything to your knowledge to cause this BOM to appear

Comment: look in all of your included files for an apostrophe outside of the <?php ?> tags.

Comment: ok thats strange, so it seems like my other application which has its webservices php code stored in a sister folder runs fine, with the same echo statement working. That means something, somewhere is in the original sub folder's php files which is not where its supposed to be! Ok, ill have a quick look, thank goodness it has othing to do with my server or php version that I recently changed.

Comment: FINALLY! Thank you so MUCH Orangephil!! sheesh, im going to delete all my compensation coding that I did in efforts to remove the first 3 characters of my server responses! Awesome. If I could give you 500 points, I really would have! Write your suggestion up as an answer and I'll have it ticked right away! thank you

Comment: Care to leave an answer orange pill so that i can mark it as the correct answer? I dont want this post lingering about